# Vkontakte authentication using django-social-auth

Tags: authentication, django-socialauth, vk

I have a problem integrating Vkontakte authentication using django-social-auth (https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth). I know that I have set everything right with AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS as well as the API_KEYS and SECRETS for VKONTAKTE but still it does not work. I also have an authentication with Facebook and it works fine so I know that I am doing it right. Django-Social-Auth's documentation says about adding some JS script to make the authentication work but doesn't even provide some useful information about the script.

Can somebody provide some useful information about this? If you could provide some very nice tutorial on how to implement Vkontakte authentication using django-social-auth that would be great!

Thanks a lot guys! =)

Answer (score 0):

If the url you're using is something like `"http://localhost:8000/login/vkontakte/"`, try to change it to `"http://localhost:8000/login/vkontakte-oauth2/"`.